# javascript fetch return empty data

Tags: javascript

i have problem. Why fetch no return data?
When i'm try this request in postman this request return data.

Postman screen shot:

[image]

Chrome DevTools return screen shot:

[image]

javascript code:

```
function getAllRestaurant() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
  };

  fetch(store.state.apiUrl + 'restaurant', requestOptions)
      .then(data => console.log('Data from server: ', data))
      .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error));
}
```

Comment: What does it return? Anything, any output? Kinda missing a fair bit of info here.

Comment: Please show your errors as text, not as images.

Comment: Just one note, althought your question is lacking some more info, you can try to return data.json(), and chain another then below, and do the console.log() there

Comment: There's no need to send `Content-type:` in `GET` request, since it doesn't have any content.

Comment: From what you've shown us, it looks like it is working. Or at least, the fetch is coming back successfully (Status 200). What is the output of your console.log?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. To see the actual JSON data, you need to call its `json()` method, which returns another promise.

```
function getAllRestaurant() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { ...authHeader(),
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
  };

  fetch(store.state.apiUrl + 'restaurant', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json().then(data => console.log(data)))
    .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I'm replace

in my vuex module

```
getAllRestaurant({ commit }) {
    commit('getAllRestaurantRequest');

    restaurantService.getAllRestaurant()
        .then(
            restaurant => commit('getAllRestaurantSuccess', restaurant),
            error => commit('getAllRestaurantFailure', error)
        );
  },
```

To:

```
  getAllRestaurant({ commit }) {
    commit('getAllRestaurantRequest');

    restaurantService.getAllRestaurant()
        .then(response => response.json().then(data => commit('getAllRestaurantSuccess', data)))
        .catch(error => commit('getAllRestaurantFailure', error));
  },
```

And work good. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It is because of missing the content type specified. Here you need to json() method to typecast the request to json form.

Just adding the content type conversion will resolve this issue.

Change the following code

```
function getAllRestaurant() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
  };

  fetch(store.state.apiUrl + 'restaurant', requestOptions)
      .then(data => console.log('Data from server: ', data))
      .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error));
}
```

To

```
function getAllRestaurant() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
  };

  fetch(store.state.apiUrl + 'restaurant', requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log('Data from server: ', data))
      .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error));
}
```

adding `.then(res => res.json())` will resolve this isssue.